# Facebook Marketing API Long Lived Tokens Spam Filtering

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-marketing-api

My team is working on app that will use the Facebook Marketing API to make changes using users access tokens.

I read on this documentation post about getting a long lived access token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#generate-long-lived-token

That Facebook recommends getting a long lived access token per client in order to “Avoid triggering Facebook’s automated spam systems”.

Our app is hosted on Heroku which means that the IP address sending the calls to Facebook using users access tokens won’t be consistent. Is this going to cause any issues with Facebooks automated spam systems?

If yes then we will probably not be hosting on Heroku.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: it´s completely irrelevant to rate limiting what hosting option you are using...just use an extended page token and make sure you aren´t doing too many calls per token.

Comment: isn´t the marketing api bound to pages? nevermind if not, i have never used it. it does not make any difference though, if it works.

Comment: What you are quoting there is meant in regard to browsers/native apps first and foremost.